# Stability of $\ddot{x}+c \dot{x}+x(1-x)=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

Let
$$\ddot{x}+c \dot{x}+x(1-x)=0  $$
Find sufficient conditions for $c$ such that the solution follows this properties:

$$\lim_{t \to -\infty}x(t)=0 \ \ \ \lim_{t \to \infty}x(t)=1 \ \ \ \dot{x}>0 \ \ \forall t$$

My attempt: I change the differential equation into a system of differential equations. I have the following:

\begin{align}
 \dot{x}_1 &= x_2\\
 \dot{x}_2 &= -cx_2-x_1+x_1^2.
\end{align}

Then, I calculate the equilibrium and get $P_1 = (0,0)$ and $P_2 = (1,0)$. The problem arises when I analyze the stability.  For $P_1$ the point must be inestable and for $P_2$ stable. But I have some problems with the characteristic polynomial. For $P_1$ I got
$$\lambda^2+c\lambda+1,$$
and for $P_2$ I got
$$\lambda^2+c\lambda-1.$$
However, I do not know how I could assure both conditions in my problem.

Any help?

Comment: I too had issues getting appropriate values of $c$. I think one requires $c$ to be complex.

Comment: It could be, or maybe the exercise is wrong

Comment: Even for complex $c$ I think it fails. $P_2$ can only ever be either a saddle point or an orbit.